# PDFkit write directly to the HTTP response

Tags: python, pdfkit

I have a server which I dont have write access,I want to generate a pdf with pdfkit and just write its contents to the HTTP response without saving first the file to a temp file in the server.The following code doesn't work

```
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()
print "Content-Type: application/pdf;\n"

import base64
from io import BytesIO
import sys
import pdfkit

data=pdfkit.from_string("asfddsgsdfg", False, {
    'page-size': 'Letter',
    'margin-top': '0.75in',
    'margin-right': '0.75in',
    'margin-bottom': '0.75in',
    'margin-left': '0.75in',
    'encoding': "UTF-8",
    'orientation': 'Landscape'
})

sys.stdout.write(data)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some code from my Django project as example:

```
import pdfkit

def program2pdf(filename):

    programconfig = ProgramConfig.get_solo()
    programconfig.downloaded += 1
    programconfig.save()

    config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf=settings.PDF_WKHTMLTOPDF)

    content = render_to_string(
        'program/item2pdf.html', {
            'events': Event.objects.all(), 
            'abs_path': settings.PDF_ADDRESS,
            'programconfig': programconfig
        }
    )

    pdf = pdfkit.PDFKit(content, "string", configuration=config).to_pdf()

    response = HttpResponse(pdf)
    response['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
    response['Content-disposition'] = 'attachment;filename='
    response['Content-disposition'] += programconfig.get_filename

    return response
```

Comment: where is the render_to_string method comming from? It is a django shortcut?

Comment: @Jcc.Sanabria `from django.template.loader import render_to_string`